# Setting textfields as integers or doubles in JavaFX JDBC Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am writting a program where the user can input a set of data which will directly go into a database. Hence, where the user can input all the data he needs to fill in to insert it into the database, I need to make two of the textfields as integers and one as a double. However, I cannot seem to find what is the code to set a textfield as integer or double, instead of doing:
"expeditionDate.setText(Date)". Therefore, I was hoping if anyone knows the set of code to set a textfield as a integer or double. However, I cannot cast it into a String as I will need to make calcualtions using the data.

```
void setTextField(String Date, double Time , int Altitude, int Distance, String Notes) {

   
        expeditionDate.setText(Date);
        expeditionTime.(Time);;
        expeditionAltitude.setText(Altitude);;
        expeditionDistance = Distance;
        expeditionNotes.setText(Notes);
        
        

    }
```

Comment: You have to convert the int or double to a string to set the field.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, that was what I was thinking, however, I need the input to stay as an integer or double, as I will have to calculate the total distance, altitude and time. But if I convert both of them to a string, will it stop me from making those calculations?

Comment: Keep the values separately. You have no choice but to use strings for the actual setText calls.

Comment: @greg-449 *”You have no choice but to use Strings”*. There are other choices. You can set a [`TextFormatter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) on the text field and set the value of the formatter.

Comment: @James_D is correct.  Here's a tutorial I wrote: https://www.pragmaticcoding.ca/javafx/elements/textformatter/

Comment: @DaveB impressive writeup on what is historically a really poorly documented feature.